# efficiently counting no of elements in one list which are less than element in some other list

Tags: python

it was my test but time is over now and i love to know the answer

I have two list

```
first_list = [2, 10, 5, 4, 8]
second_list = [3, 1, 7, 8]
```

I want to count the number of elements from `first_list` which are less than every element in `second_list`
like

```
2       < 3 ans 1
_       < 1 ans 0
2, 5, 4 < 7 ans 3
2,5,4,8 < 8 ans 4
```

which lastly returns list `[1,0,3,4]`

```py
count = []
sorted_list = sorted(first_list)
for i in second_list:
    c = 0
    for j in sorted_list:
        if j <= i:
            c += 1
        else:
            break
    count.append(c)
```

This was my most optimized method, but got `code stopped due to runtime error`.

Comment: What runtime error did you get?  What test cases?

Comment: Ah ... is your error that you exceeded the allowed execution time for a particular test case?  Are the test cases much larger?

Comment: test cases was hidden and only error was  code stopped due to runtime error

Comment: I'm confused by several parts of this question. Your code uses `first_list` and `second_list`, but you also refer to `a` and `b`? And I'm not sure what `ans` means. Really nothing in the second code block makes any sense to me.

Comment: I believe he's just looking for a more efficient version of this code.

Comment: Is `runtime error` the grader's expression for exceeding a time limit?  The usual meaning of that phrase is an unspecified error detected while the program was running.

Comment: @Prune yeah I exceeded time limit

Comment: Looks like there's a contradiction in your words and your test result too. You said less than every element, yet you used <=. Some clarification would be nice, though I'm leaning towards less than or equal to.

Comment: You can add the code in try except block. In the except block add 'pass'. It is usually a case with online judges. This is a hack used to handle run time errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly improve the execution speed for large lists.  Start by sorting the list you search:

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 8, 10]
b = [3, 1, 7, 8]
```

Now, for each element of `b`, do a binary search on `a`, returning the index where that value would fit into `a`.  That index tells you how many elements of `a` are less than that value.

Sorting the list is **O(n log n)**; the search is **O(log n)**.  Your previous search is **O(n)** (i.e. slower).

If you want to improve on this even more, also sort your `b` list (but remember the original order, so you know where the answers belong).  Start in the middle of the `b` list; find that element.  Now split the `a` list at that point; further searches will fall into only one partition or the other.  Also split the `b` list, so you know which portion of `a` to use.  Continue that process with each of the new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The standard included module [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) could be used for this purpose, (to do a binary search).

```
import bisect

def main():
    a = [2, 10, 5, 4, 8]
    a.sort()
    b = [3, 1, 7, 8]

    for item in b:
        print(item, bsearch(a, item))


def bsearch(arr, key):
    'Find rightmost value less than or equal to x'
    i = bisect.bisect_right(arr, key)
    if i:
        return arr[:i]
    else:
        return []

main()
```

Prints:

```
3 [2]
1 []
7 [2, 4, 5]
8 [2, 4, 5, 8]
```

EDIT: If you just need the counts instead of the items, you could modify `bsearch` to return `i` instead of `arr[:i]`.

```
def bsearch(arr, key):
    'Find rightmost value less than or equal to x'
    i = bisect.bisect_right(arr, key)
    if i:
        return i
    else:
        return 0
```